# Twitter Streaming API .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am currently trying to write some code to consumer the user stream from the Twitter streaming API:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/user_streams

I am struggling to connect to it using basic auth and assume (the docs don't say) that OAuth is required.

However I cannot find a Twitter .NET library that supports streaming and OAuth (actually, haven't found any with decent samples/docs on consuming the streaming API).

Does anyone know of any? Currently I have written my own code to consume the sample stream using C# and dynamic but really don't want to have to implement OAuth (people say its complex).

Edit:

Although, I have been able to get an access token and access token secret via the TweetSharp library fine, I have no clue on how to generate the required headers/implement oauth, which could be another option I guess rather than a full library.

Short version:

- Looking for a library that supports streaming API and OAuth
- Advise on implementing OAuth manually

Comment: Basic auth isn't allowed anymore.

Comment: thanks, lkke, thought so judging on the 401 I kept getting

Comment: Maybe [Twitter API + OAuth: Can't send status updates, getting 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971369/twitter-api-oauth-cant-send-status-updates-getting-401) can help.

Comment: @Thomas my app's permissions are fine, posted an update to a test account fine, its just the streaming api is quite new and not supported by the main wrapper libraries that I can find.

Comment: Why aren't you using DotNetOpenAuth? They even have examples for working with twitter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Shannon Whitley post:
[Twitter oAuth with .NET](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/)

Answer (score 6):

As I explained in this post [Consuming twitter stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189032/consuming-twitter-stream-api/11860726#11860726), Tweetinvi API provides easy to configure Streaming API access.

You can download it here : http://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/

A Stream class exist and will enable you to easily implement a delegate to read the content coming from Twitter.

The class has been tested on real-life projects and is able to retrieve millions of tweets per day.

I am one of the developer working on the project.

Comment: can u guide me to tutorial/example plz

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks i got it resolved :) ... Kudos for putting together such an awesome lib

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) library in the past, which supports OAuth.

Comment: no support for streaming api but as mentioned in my answer I already use it for oauth credential creation.

Comment: can u please point to sample code? im kinda lost

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar just follow the link to TweetSharp, you'll find several examples there.